# LED-Monitor-Firmware reverse engineering / disassembly => replace manufacturer startup logo

Tags: reverse-engineering, firmware, binary, monitor

I have a display from a disassembled led-monitor (Wortmann Terra 2446W), that I want to use for a SmartMirror-project.
Unfortunately, the monitor shows a big manufacturer logo when connected to power, therefore I am checking now, wether I maybe could be able to replace that logo or not.

The monitor firmware is possibly located on the only non-volatile memory chip I could find on the controller-board, a MX25L4006E (4MBit SI NOR-Flash). Since this chip is programmable via flashrom-utility (and listed as fully supported) and I have a flashrom-compatible programmer based on a FTDI2232H, I think I should be able to read the firmware from the flash / write a modified version back.

Has anybody ever replaced such an embedded logo, and maybe has got some hints on how to possibly identify/reverse-engineer the address-ranges and format of the integrated boot-logo ? Will eventually binwalk be able to directly identify it, e.g. in the same way that for example testdisk & photorec identify filetypes based on raw data bytes (fileheaders, block-formats e.g.) 
I will update this question as soon as I successfully obtained the binary firmware file...
Thanks in advance for any help, Oliver

Comment: If acceptable, it would be far simpler to just disable the backlight for just enough time so that the logo cannot be seen. Messing with the firmware seems risky to me, it might break the monitor.

Comment: The logo is being displayed, before connection to the pc is established. I am switching its power-supply off via a relais controlled by the raspberry pi, as soon as motion-sensor does not detect any motion for a certain period of time. So, unfortunately, backlight-control doesn`t get me further here ..